# Assistance Needed with Simulating Data from Kepware to AWS RDS via IoT Core and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, iot, aws-iot

`With the help of IoT Core and AWS Lambda, I am attempting to simulate data from Kepware and transfer it to IoT Core move it to AWS RDS (MySQL) Using Lambda Function and IoT Rule.
However, I am having some trouble accomplishing that, though.

PFA the code hat i am using in lambda function.

```
import boto3
import json
import pymysql
from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient

# Set your AWS region
region = 'ap-south-1'

# Set the name of your thing
#thing_name = 'Testing-thing'

# Set your RDS database configuration
db_host = 's3-rds-database.ckjopgjmqq4v.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
db_user = 'rdsdata'
db_password = 'test1234'
db_name = 'rdsdb'
db_table = 'rdstable'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    def process_message(client, userdata, message):
        try:
        # Extract the message payload
            payload = json.loads(message.payload.decode('utf-8'))
            connection = pymysql.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user, password=db_password, db=db_name)

            #for i in range(4):
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            timestamp = payload['timestamp']
            good_units = payload['ankit.Device1.OEE_Data_line_csv_GOOD_UNITS']
            phase = payload['ankit.Device1.OEE_Data_line_csv_PHASE']
            status = payload['ankit.Device1.OEE_Data_line_csv_STATUS']
            total_units = payload['ankit.Device1.OEE_Data_line_csv_TOTAL_UNITS']
           
            # Insert the message into the database table
            insert_query = f"""INSERT INTO {db_table} (timestamp, good_units, phase, status, total_units) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
            cursor.execute(insert_query, (timestamp, good_units, phase, status, total_units))
            connection.commit()
            connection.close()

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error processing message: {str(e)}')
    try:
    # Create an AWS IoT MQTT client
        iot_client = AWSIoTMQTTClient('Testing-thing')
        iot_client.configureEndpoint('a1ow02e8ll6auc-ats.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com', 8883)
        iot_client.configureCredentials('crt/rootCA.pem', 'crt/private.key', 'crt/certificate.crt')
        #iot_client.configureOfflinePublishQueueing(-1)  # Infinite offline Publish queueing
        #iot_client.configureDrainingFrequency(2)  # Draining: 2 Hz
        #iot_client.configureConnectDisconnectTimeout(10) # 10 sec
        #iot_client.configureMQTTOperationTimeout(10)  # 5 sec

        iot_client.connect()
        topic = 'iotdata'
        iot_client.subscribe(topic, 1, process_message)

        return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Subscribed to MQTT topic'}

    except Exception as e:
        return {'statusCode': 500}
```

I am looking for the solution for the issue that i am facing.`